# What am I doing wrong with this Tkinter formatting?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a Tkinter application using much cleaner formatting using inspiration from Bryan Oakley's suggestion from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466561/best-way-to-structure-a-tkinter-application).

```
import tkinter as tk

class MainApplication(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent

        # Set start-up screen width and height
        screen_width = self.parent.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = self.parent.winfo_screenheight()
        self.parent.geometry(f"{screen_width}x{screen_height}")

        # Adding Header
        self.header = Header(self)
        self.header.pack(side="top", fill="x")

class Header(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame(parent, height=50, bg="#000000")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    MainApplication(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

However, when running this code, I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Header' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

**tk.Frame** in the `Header` class has no impact because the frame is not initialized with the class (tk.Frame) you are inheriting. hence when you use  `self.header.pack(side="top", fill="x")` you are getting the error.You can use the below method which creates a frame object and places it in the init method. or you can add one more method inside the `Header` class which will return the frame object, thereby you can place it using pack in your `MainApplication` class

```
import tkinter as tk

class MainApplication(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent

        # Set start-up screen width and height
        screen_width = self.parent.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = self.parent.winfo_screenheight()
        self.parent.geometry(f"{screen_width}x{screen_height}")
        Header(self.parent)


class Header(object):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.parent, height=50, bg="#000000")
        self.frame.pack(side="top", fill="x")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    MainApplication(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This answer would be better if you described what you changed. Otherwise we have to compare this code to the original line-by-line and character-by-character.

Comment: @BryanOakley added the explanation. please correct me if anything wrong

Comment: Thanks @martineau, yes by tk.Frame i meant the base class inherited in Header class created by vexem

Answer (score 1):

Your `Header` class isn't properly inheriting from `tk.Frame`. You need to make sure the `__init__` method of the base class is called just like you do in `MainApplication`.

```
class Header(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        ...
```

Comment: Bryan, `super()` was [added to Python 2.2](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.2.html) in late December 2001, and it's now the last quarter of 2021 and Python 3.10 is available, so I humbly suggest you start using `super()` when defining subclasses. ;¬)

Comment: @martineau: yes, I know. I was being consistent with the rest of the code.

Comment: I see, but note that the OP was only being consistent with an [answer of *yours*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17470842/355230) dated Jul 4 '13 — so I guess it's not quite as much of an anachronism as I thought, but still…